# direction on (My)SQL left/right/inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

While getting a list of restaurant I want to join rating data in this list.

For example

```
Table1 – restaurant
Columns: id, name, latitude, longitude
```

and

```
Table2 – ratings
Columns: id, restaurant_id, rating (value options: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Constructed this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(ratings.rating) AS total_rating_count 
FROM restaurants 
INNER JOIN ratings 
    ON ratings.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
```

This only returns me 1 restaurant. I also need the amount of ratings available per restaurant in able to calculate average rating.

Can use some direction on this.

**EDIT**:
And while we are at it, I want to join another table with comments linked to restaurant.
I should dive into this at the same time:
[What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you provide some sample rows, the desired result of your query and the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  *, AVG(ratings.rating) AS avg_rating_count 
FROM 
  restaurants 
    INNER JOIN ratings ON ratings.restaurant_id = restaurants.id 
GROUP BY 
  restaurants.id
```

-since you've mentioned average value, I've placed [AVG()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function in query. But be aware that this is invalid in normal SQL (mixing of non-group columns with group functions) - and in terms of MySQL DBMS doesn't specify which row will be returned.

Comment: getting closer, AVG works and returns 2 records now. 2 is the amount of restaurants that actually have ratings. I need, however the complete list of restaurant even though there is no rating.

Comment: @SanJayFalcon then it should be mentioned in question together with sample data & desired output. You can achieve that with `LEFT JOIN`